# When does a certain set lose its connectedness?

Tags: calculus, connectedness

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous, everywhere-differentiable, and bounded above by $u$.  Let $S_k = \{x | f(x) \le k \}$ (thus, $S_u = \mathbb{R}^n$).  Imagine sliding $k$ down continuously from $u$.  Then $S_k$ would lose path-connectedness right at the moment that the line $f(x) = k$ becomes tangent to the global maximum $g$ of $f(x)$, since any further decrease in $k$ will cause $g \notin S_k$, and poking a hole in $\mathbb{R}$ causes it to lose path-connectedness.

What is the equivalent condition if we change the domain of $f$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: If you consider a real-valued function like $arctan(x)$ that is increasing but bounded, the sets $S_k$ remain path-connected for all $k$.

Answer (score 1):

While there's no nice equivalent condition for the set losing path connectedness, there is a nice equivalent statement:

If $f\colon \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has a unique global maximum $g$, then the set $S_k$ will lose [simple connectedness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected) right at $k=g$.

In many ways, simple connectedness is the one-dimension-higher analogue of path-connectedness.  This generalizes to [$n$-connectedness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-connected), which lets you take the above statement to even higher dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an equivalent condition.  Consider $f:{\Bbb R}^2\to{\Bbb R}:(x,y)\mapsto -x^2-y^2$, which is bounded above, but for which the corresponding $S_k$ would be connected for any $k$.

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't mean that no condition exists - it just means that the condition we find should be unmeetable in your example function.

Comment: Then you may want to clarify what you meant by "equivalent condition".  We're a very precise  bunch of people around here.